# Using python for getting data out from a tektronix oscilliscope

Tags: pyvisa

```
import visa 
import numpy as np
from struct import unpack
import pylab

rm = visa.ResourceManager()
rm.list_resources()
inst = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::1::INSTR',write_termination= '\n')

print(inst.query("*IDN?"))
print(rm)
print(inst)
values = np.array(inst.query_ascii_values('CURV?', converter='s'))
#values1=inst.write_ascii_values('WLISt:WAVeform:DATA somename,', values, converter='s')
```

len(values)
   print(values)

Hi all,
I am really new with Python and programming.  I am trying to get a waveform from a Tektronix oscilloscope (TDS 460 A).  I am using a GPIB  (GPIB USB-HS) to transfer data. With the code written above, I am able to connect with the oscilloscope. I have some very basic questions. When I print(values), it is giving me a string.  I was wondering what is that string? Is it the same as the address of the instrument? Now as I am connected with the instrument, how can I proceed further? My ultimate aim is to get the trace from multiple channels of the scope.

Comment: Undoubtedly the string in some way represents the data.  Are you familiar with digitizing a signal?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: No I am not.  Could you please provide me a starting point?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: My output for print(data) is - {b'#3500jkjjjjjkjjjjjkkkjjjjjjkjjkkikjkjkjkjjjjkjkjjkkkjjjjkkjjjjjkjjjjkjkkjjjjjjkjjjjjjkjkkjkjkjjjkkkjkkjkkjjjjjjjkjkkkjkjjjkjjkkjkjjjjjijjjkjjjkkjjkjkjjkkjjjjikkjjkjjjkjjjjjjjkjjkjjkjjjkkjjkjijjijkjjjkjkjjkjkjjkkjkjjjkjjjjjjkjjjjkjjjkjkjjjkkkjjjjjjikkkjjkkjkjjjjkjkjjjjjkkjkjjjjjjijiijjkkjkkjjjkijkjjkjjkijjjjjkjkkjjjkjjjkjijjjjjkjjjkkkjkkjjkjjjjjjjjjjkjjkijjjjjkkjijkjjjkjjkjjjkjkjjjjjjjjkjjjjjkjkjjkjjjjjjkkkjkkjjkjkkjjkijjjjkkjkjkjikjjjjjjjjjjijjjjikjjjkjjjjkjijkkjjkjjjjjjjjijjjjkjjjkjikjkjkkjkjkjjjjjj\n'} -I am not sure what it is?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: My output for print values is - {['#3500\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00............ \n] Could you please explain what is it? What does the number 3500 represent?

Comment: Looks like you're going to need a Tektronix manual to decipher that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
from struct import unpack
import pyvisa as visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
print(rm)

def acquire(channel, port):
    try:
        scope = rm.open_resource(port)
        scope.write("DATA:SOURCE " + channel)
        scope.write('DATA:WIDTH 1')
        scope.write('DATA:ENC RPB')
        ymult = float(scope.ask('WFMPRE:YMULT?'))
        yzero = float(scope.ask('WFMPRE:YZERO?'))
        yoff = float(scope.ask('WFMPRE:YOFF?'))
        xincr = float(scope.ask('WFMPRE:XINCR?'))
        xdelay = float(scope.query('HORizontal:POSition?'))
        scope.write('CURVE?')
        data = scope.read_raw()
        headerlen = 2 + int(data[1])
        header = data[:headerlen]
        ADC_wave = data[headerlen:-1]
        ADC_wave = np.array(unpack('%sB' % len(ADC_wave),ADC_wave))
        Volts = (ADC_wave - yoff) * ymult  + yzero
        Time = np.arange(0, (xincr * len(Volts)), xincr)-((xincr * len(Volts))/2-xdelay)
        return Time,Volts
    except IndexError:
        return 0,0
```